# Display only recently modified tabs when editing multiple files in Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, ide

In Eclipse 3.x, if you were working on say 60 files at once, but you were only editing 4 in a particular session, then the tabs for these four would tend to stay displayed throughout. For example: if I edit tab 1, and then tab 60, tab 1 will still be displayed and I can switch back to it quickly.

However in Eclipse 4.x, it seems displayed tabs have no relevance to editing history. For example: if I edit tab 1, and then edit tab 60, tab 1 will not be displayed: I will have to use the dropdown to re-select it.

Is there any way to restore the functionality of Eclipse 3.x, in that recent or session tabs stay displayed when switching between documents?

Comment: You should have a look at the Mylyn plugin, which will automatically reduce the number of visible UI elements (including editors) depending on what you do.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour for the new Windows 7 style of Eclipse 4: see [Eclipse bug 389169](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389169).

You can restore the previous behaviour - and also the previous style - by selecting the *Classic* theme in *General > Appearance*.